# SQLOLEDB Deprecated

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, mfc, oledb

I have been browsing for an answer from last one month.
Now I could not resist myself to post it here and discuss my observations with experts.
Please find my observations/doubt:

I am using SQLOLEDB and SQL Server 2008 R2
As per MSDN, The commercial release of Microsoft SQL Server, codename "Denali"(SQL Server 2012) will be the last release to support OLEDB.
Reference : [MSDN BLOG](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/09/13/microsoft-sql-server-oledb-provider-deprecation-announcement.aspx)

On the other hand it is mentioned that the OLEDB data consumers are supported till SQL Server 2014
Reference : [MSDN Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn538994(v=sql.120).aspx)

Now I need to upgrade my tool to work with SQL Server 2012 and all of the later version.
However I checked my application with SQL Server 2012 and found working fine without changing anything.

So not sure how it is working and which announcement shall i follow and shall i change my code and 
switch to other DB access methodology(SQL Native, ODBC)
Any suggestion will be really helpful.

Many Many Thanks in advance.

Few more link on Stack overflow itself : [Stack overflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37894058/what-are-the-differences-between-oledb-odbc-drivers-when-connecting-to-sql-serve)

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server 2012 is the last version to support SQL OLE DB connections. So, if you're on SQL Server 2012, then you're still fine.

For future versions, Microsoft gives this article to convert your application from OLE DB to ODBC - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh967418.aspx

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2014 and it is working here as well.
Don't know what's is being messed up :P

Comment: not anymore https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlnativeclient/2017/10/06/announcing-the-new-release-of-ole-db-driver-for-sql-server/